# How to change the color of the text selection handle of one of my EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-theme, android-styles

I have some of my EditText that are placed on a blue background, and for theses EditText i would like to setup a white color for the text selection handles (without uploading new png image if possible on lollipop or newer)

[image]

i try to add `<item name="android:colorAccent">#ffffffff</item>` in the style of my custom EditText like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <!-- EditText on a blue background -->
  <style name="BlueBGTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item> <!-- this will also remove all paddings -->  
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item> <!-- this to use android:textColor as the cursor color. -->  
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ffffffff</item> 
  </style>

  <!-- default EditText -->
  <style name="AppTheme.EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item> <!-- this will also remove all paddings -->  
  </style>

  <!-- default Theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item> <!-- use to setup the color of the text selection handles -->   
    <item name="@attr/BlueBGTextViewStyle">@style/BlueBGTextView</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

but it's not work :( what did i miss ?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify `textColorHighlight` property in xml

Sample

```
android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000"
```

To change the handles, define a style with colorControlActivated property

```
<style name="BlueBGTextView">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

and set it as a theme to your `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/BlueBGTextView"/>
```

Comment: no it's didn't work :( i want to change it ONLY for <style name="BlueBGTextView" ... i try to add it and it's change nothing

Comment: Let me clarify. You want to change the text highlight background?

Comment: OK. First I think that the handles are outside the styling scope of `EditText`. Therefore, you need to modify the actual `theme` of the view, not the style. I updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: no not work, now i have No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlActivated' :(

Comment: You should use theme instead of style - https://medium.com/me/stats/post/838616e9e327

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the Theme.MaterialComponents as the App Theme then the ***handle color will follow your **Primary** color***.

And also be aware of Light/Dark mode in theme.xml and on your testing phone should be matched.

If your phone running on Dark mode then add `colorPrimary` item for `values-night/theme.xml`, otherwise add for `values/themes.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```